# How should I use view.raw.php properly

Tags: component, development, recommended-practices, view

I'm trying to add a custom `JToolbar` button to my list view that will export the list contents to excel. I created a new task in my list controller to render the raw view class in a file called view.raw.php. However I can't get the content to load the raw data only.

I copied the relevant controller code from com_banners tracks.raw.php controller

Controller method:

```
public function exportToExcel()
{
    // Get the document object.
    $document   = JFactory::getDocument();
    $vName      = 'Mylist';
    $vFormat    = 'raw';

    // Get and render the view.
    if ($view = $this->getView($vName, $vFormat))
    {
        // Get the model for the view.
        $model = $this->getModel($vName);

        // Push the model into the view (as default).
        $view->setModel($model, true);

        // Push document object into the view.
        $view->document = $document;

        $view->display();
    }
}
```

And a simple test display method in my view.raw.php file:

```
public function display($tpl = null)
{
   echo "Test";
}
```

This displays "Test" but loads the template too.

I've tried using `$document->setType('Raw')` but this is giving me an

> Unable to load renderer class

error.

The reason for this is that it is looking for

> libraries/joomla/document/raw/renderer/modules.php

which does not exist.

Maybe I'm going about this in the wrong way but how should I do this correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the document type in the URL call with `format=raw`. Joomla will then automatically load the `view.raw.php` file. You don't even need a special controller for that.

To create the toolbar button you can use this:

```
    $bar = JToolBar::getInstance('toolbar');
    $bar->appendButton('Custom', '<button onclick="window.location.href = \'http://www.google.com\';">Export</button>', 'export');
```

Comment: But how to pass the URL to the toolbar button? AFAIK it is not possible, you can only specify controller's name and task.

Comment: Using `JToolbarHelper` it's not possible, but it should be possible using `JToolbar->appendButton()` like we don for the batch button. I'll check :)